# Is my backbone.js compromised?

Tags: javascript, magento, backbone.js

I am using Magento and they recently released a security scan tool. I had a file that was flagged as compromised. Here is the file-

// Backbone.js 0.9.2

```
            // (c) 2010-2012 Jeremy Ashkenas, DocumentCloud Inc.
            // Backbone may be freely distributed under the MIT license.
            // For all details and documentation:
            // http://backbonejs.org
            (function(){var l=this,y=l.Backbone,z=Array.prototype.slice,A=Array.prototype.splice,g;g="undefined"!==typeof exports?exports:l.Backbone={};g.VERSION="0.9.2";var f=l._;!f&&"undefined"!==typeof require&&(f=require("underscore"));var i=l.jQuery||l.Zepto||l.ender;g.setDomLibrary=function(a){i=a};g.noConflict=function(){l.Backbone=y;return this};g.emulateHTTP=!1;g.emulateJSON=!1;var p=/\s+/,k=g.Events={on:function(a,b,c){var d,e,f,g,j;if(!b)return this;a=a.split(p);for(d=this._callbacks||(this._callbacks=
            {});e=a.shift();)f=(j=d[e])?j.tail:{},f.next=g={},f.context=c,f.callback=b,d[e]={tail:g,next:j?j.next:f};return this},off:function(a,b,c){var d,e,h,g,j,q;if(e=this._callbacks){if(!a&&!b&&!c)return delete this._callbacks,this;for(a=a?a.split(p):f.keys(e);d=a.shift();)if(h=e[d],delete e[d],h&&(b||c))for(g=h.tail;(h=h.next)!==g;)if(j=h.callback,q=h.context,b&&j!==b||c&&q!==c)this.on(d,j,q);return this}},trigger:function(a){var b,c,d,e,f,g;if(!(d=this._callbacks))return this;f=d.all;a=a.split(p);for(g=
            z.call(arguments,1);b=a.shift();){if(c=d[b])for(e=c.tail;(c=c.next)!==e;)c.callback.apply(c.context||this,g);if(c=f){e=c.tail;for(b=[b].concat(g);(c=c.next)!==e;)c.callback.apply(c.context||this,b)}}return this}};k.bind=k.on;k.unbind=k.off;var o=g.Model=function(a,b){var c;a||(a={});b&&b.parse&&(a=this.parse(a));if(c=n(this,"defaults"))a=f.extend({},c,a);b&&b.collection&&(this.collection=b.collection);this.attributes={};this._escapedAttributes={};this.cid=f.uniqueId("c");this.changed={};this._silent=
            {};this._pending={};this.set(a,{silent:!0});this.changed={};this._silent={};this._pending={};this._previousAttributes=f.clone(this.attributes);this.initialize.apply(this,arguments)};f.extend(o.prototype,k,{changed:null,_silent:null,_pending:null,idAttribute:"id",initialize:function(){},toJSON:function(){return f.clone(this.attributes)},get:function(a){return this.attributes[a]},escape:function(a){var b;if(b=this._escapedAttributes[a])return b;b=this.get(a);return this._escapedAttributes[a]=f.escape(null==
            b?"":""+b)},has:function(a){return null!=this.get(a)},set:function(a,b,c){var d,e;f.isObject(a)||null==a?(d=a,c=b):(d={},d[a]=b);c||(c={});if(!d)return this;d instanceof o&&(d=d.attributes);if(c.unset)for(e in d)d[e]=void 0;if(!this._validate(d,c))return!1;this.idAttribute in d&&(this.id=d[this.idAttribute]);var b=c.changes={},h=this.attributes,g=this._escapedAttributes,j=this._previousAttributes||{};for(e in d){a=d[e];if(!f.isEqual(h[e],a)||c.unset&&f.has(h,e))delete g[e],(c.silent?this._silent:
            b)[e]=!0;c.unset?delete h[e]:h[e]=a;!f.isEqual(j[e],a)||f.has(h,e)!=f.has(j,e)?(this.changed[e]=a,c.silent||(this._pending[e]=!0)):(delete this.changed[e],delete this._pending[e])}c.silent||this.change(c);return this},unset:function(a,b){(b||(b={})).unset=!0;return this.set(a,null,b)},clear:function(a){(a||(a={})).unset=!0;return this.set(f.clone(this.attributes),a)},fetch:function(a){var a=a?f.clone(a):{},b=this,c=a.success;a.success=function(d,e,f){if(!b.set(b.parse(d,f),a))return!1;c&&c(b,d)};
            a.error=g.wrapError(a.error,b,a);return(this.sync||g.sync).call(this,"read",this,a)},save:function(a,b,c){var d,e;f.isObject(a)||null==a?(d=a,c=b):(d={},d[a]=b);c=c?f.clone(c):{};if(c.wait){if(!this._validate(d,c))return!1;e=f.clone(this.attributes)}a=f.extend({},c,{silent:!0});if(d&&!this.set(d,c.wait?a:c))return!1;var h=this,i=c.success;c.success=function(a,b,e){b=h.parse(a,e);if(c.wait){delete c.wait;b=f.extend(d||{},b)}if(!h.set(b,c))return false;i?i(h,a):h.trigger("sync",h,a,c)};c.error=g.wrapError(c.error,
            h,c);b=this.isNew()?"create":"update";b=(this.sync||g.sync).call(this,b,this,c);c.wait&&this.set(e,a);return b},destroy:function(a){var a=a?f.clone(a):{},b=this,c=a.success,d=function(){b.trigger("destroy",b,b.collection,a)};if(this.isNew())return d(),!1;a.success=function(e){a.wait&&d();c?c(b,e):b.trigger("sync",b,e,a)};a.error=g.wrapError(a.error,b,a);var e=(this.sync||g.sync).call(this,"delete",this,a);a.wait||d();return e},url:function(){var a=n(this,"urlRoot")||n(this.collection,"url")||t();
            return this.isNew()?a:a+("/"==a.charAt(a.length-1)?"":"/")+encodeURIComponent(this.id)},parse:function(a){return a},clone:function(){return new this.constructor(this.attributes)},isNew:function(){return null==this.id},change:function(a){a||(a={});var b=this._changing;this._changing=!0;for(var c in this._silent)this._pending[c]=!0;var d=f.extend({},a.changes,this._silent);this._silent={};for(c in d)this.trigger("change:"+c,this,this.get(c),a);if(b)return this;for(;!f.isEmpty(this._pending);){this._pending=
            {};this.trigger("change",this,a);for(c in this.changed)!this._pending[c]&&!this._silent[c]&&delete this.changed[c];this._previousAttributes=f.clone(this.attributes)}this._changing=!1;return this},hasChanged:function(a){return!arguments.length?!f.isEmpty(this.changed):f.has(this.changed,a)},changedAttributes:function(a){if(!a)return this.hasChanged()?f.clone(this.changed):!1;var b,c=!1,d=this._previousAttributes,e;for(e in a)if(!f.isEqual(d[e],b=a[e]))(c||(c={}))[e]=b;return c},previous:function(a){return!arguments.length||
            !this._previousAttributes?null:this._previousAttributes[a]},previousAttributes:function(){return f.clone(this._previousAttributes)},isValid:function(){return!this.validate(this.attributes)},_validate:function(a,b){if(b.silent||!this.validate)return!0;var a=f.extend({},this.attributes,a),c=this.validate(a,b);if(!c)return!0;b&&b.error?b.error(this,c,b):this.trigger("error",this,c,b);return!1}});var r=g.Collection=function(a,b){b||(b={});b.model&&(this.model=b.model);b.comparator&&(this.comparator=b.comparator);
            this._reset();this.initialize.apply(this,arguments);a&&this.reset(a,{silent:!0,parse:b.parse})};f.extend(r.prototype,k,{model:o,initialize:function(){},toJSON:function(a){return this.map(function(b){return b.toJSON(a)})},add:function(a,b){var c,d,e,g,i,j={},k={},l=[];b||(b={});a=f.isArray(a)?a.slice():[a];c=0;for(d=a.length;c<d;c++){if(!(e=a[c]=this._prepareModel(a[c],b)))throw Error("Can't add an invalid model to a collection");g=e.cid;i=e.id;j[g]||this._byCid[g]||null!=i&&(k[i]||this._byId[i])?
            l.push(c):j[g]=k[i]=e}for(c=l.length;c--;)a.splice(l[c],1);c=0;for(d=a.length;c<d;c++)(e=a[c]).on("all",this._onModelEvent,this),this._byCid[e.cid]=e,null!=e.id&&(this._byId[e.id]=e);this.length+=d;A.apply(this.models,[null!=b.at?b.at:this.models.length,0].concat(a));this.comparator&&this.sort({silent:!0});if(b.silent)return this;c=0;for(d=this.models.length;c<d;c++)if(j[(e=this.models[c]).cid])b.index=c,e.trigger("add",e,this,b);return this},remove:function(a,b){var c,d,e,g;b||(b={});a=f.isArray(a)?
            a.slice():[a];c=0;for(d=a.length;c<d;c++)if(g=this.getByCid(a[c])||this.get(a[c]))delete this._byId[g.id],delete this._byCid[g.cid],e=this.indexOf(g),this.models.splice(e,1),this.length--,b.silent||(b.index=e,g.trigger("remove",g,this,b)),this._removeReference(g);return this},push:function(a,b){a=this._prepareModel(a,b);this.add(a,b);return a},pop:function(a){var b=this.at(this.length-1);this.remove(b,a);return b},unshift:function(a,b){a=this._prepareModel(a,b);this.add(a,f.extend({at:0},b));return a},
            shift:function(a){var b=this.at(0);this.remove(b,a);return b},get:function(a){return null==a?void 0:this._byId[null!=a.id?a.id:a]},getByCid:function(a){return a&&this._byCid[a.cid||a]},at:function(a){return this.models[a]},where:function(a){return f.isEmpty(a)?[]:this.filter(function(b){for(var c in a)if(a[c]!==b.get(c))return!1;return!0})},sort:function(a){a||(a={});if(!this.comparator)throw Error("Cannot sort a set without a comparator");var b=f.bind(this.comparator,this);1==this.comparator.length?
            this.models=this.sortBy(b):this.models.sort(b);a.silent||this.trigger("reset",this,a);return this},pluck:function(a){return f.map(this.models,function(b){return b.get(a)})},reset:function(a,b){a||(a=[]);b||(b={});for(var c=0,d=this.models.length;c<d;c++)this._removeReference(this.models[c]);this._reset();this.add(a,f.extend({silent:!0},b));b.silent||this.trigger("reset",this,b);return this},fetch:function(a){a=a?f.clone(a):{};void 0===a.parse&&(a.parse=!0);var b=this,c=a.success;a.success=function(d,
            e,f){b[a.add?"add":"reset"](b.parse(d,f),a);c&&c(b,d)};a.error=g.wrapError(a.error,b,a);return(this.sync||g.sync).call(this,"read",this,a)},create:function(a,b){var c=this,b=b?f.clone(b):{},a=this._prepareModel(a,b);if(!a)return!1;b.wait||c.add(a,b);var d=b.success;b.success=function(e,f){b.wait&&c.add(e,b);d?d(e,f):e.trigger("sync",a,f,b)};a.save(null,b);return a},parse:function(a){return a},chain:function(){return f(this.models).chain()},_reset:function(){this.length=0;this.models=[];this._byId=
            {};this._byCid={}},_prepareModel:function(a,b){b||(b={});a instanceof o?a.collection||(a.collection=this):(b.collection=this,a=new this.model(a,b),a._validate(a.attributes,b)||(a=!1));return a},_removeReference:function(a){this==a.collection&&delete a.collection;a.off("all",this._onModelEvent,this)},_onModelEvent:function(a,b,c,d){("add"==a||"remove"==a)&&c!=this||("destroy"==a&&this.remove(b,d),b&&a==="change:"+b.idAttribute&&(delete this._byId[b.previous(b.idAttribute)],this._byId[b.id]=b),this.trigger.apply(this,
            arguments))}});f.each("forEach,each,map,reduce,reduceRight,find,detect,filter,select,reject,every,all,some,any,include,contains,invoke,max,min,sortBy,sortedIndex,toArray,size,first,initial,rest,last,without,indexOf,shuffle,lastIndexOf,isEmpty,groupBy".split(","),function(a){r.prototype[a]=function(){return f[a].apply(f,[this.models].concat(f.toArray(arguments)))}});var u=g.Router=function(a){a||(a={});a.routes&&(this.routes=a.routes);this._bindRoutes();this.initialize.apply(this,arguments)},B=/:\w+/g,
            C=/\*\w+/g,D=/[-[\]{}()+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g;f.extend(u.prototype,k,{initialize:function(){},route:function(a,b,c){g.history||(g.history=new m);f.isRegExp(a)||(a=this._routeToRegExp(a));c||(c=this[b]);g.history.route(a,f.bind(function(d){d=this._extractParameters(a,d);c&&c.apply(this,d);this.trigger.apply(this,["route:"+b].concat(d));g.history.trigger("route",this,b,d)},this));return this},navigate:function(a,b){g.history.navigate(a,b)},_bindRoutes:function(){if(this.routes){var a=[],b;for(b in this.routes)a.unshift([b,
            this.routes[b]]);b=0;for(var c=a.length;b<c;b++)this.route(a[b][0],a[b][1],this[a[b][1]])}},_routeToRegExp:function(a){a=a.replace(D,"\\$&").replace(B,"([^/]+)").replace(C,"(.*?)");return RegExp("^"+a+"$")},_extractParameters:function(a,b){return a.exec(b).slice(1)}});var m=g.History=function(){this.handlers=[];f.bindAll(this,"checkUrl")},s=/^[#\/]/,E=/msie [\w.]+/;m.started=!1;f.extend(m.prototype,k,{interval:50,getHash:function(a){return(a=(a?a.location:window.location).href.match(/#(.*)$/))?a[1]:
            ""},getFragment:function(a,b){if(null==a)if(this._hasPushState||b){var a=window.location.pathname,c=window.location.search;c&&(a+=c)}else a=this.getHash();a.indexOf(this.options.root)||(a=a.substr(this.options.root.length));return a.replace(s,"")},start:function(a){if(m.started)throw Error("Backbone.history has already been started");m.started=!0;this.options=f.extend({},{root:"/"},this.options,a);this._wantsHashChange=!1!==this.options.hashChange;this._wantsPushState=!!this.options.pushState;this._hasPushState=
            !(!this.options.pushState||!window.history||!window.history.pushState);var a=this.getFragment(),b=document.documentMode;if(b=E.exec(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())&&(!b||7>=b))this.iframe=i('<iframe src="javascript:0" tabindex="-1" />').hide().appendTo("body")[0].contentWindow,this.navigate(a);this._hasPushState?i(window).bind("popstate",this.checkUrl):this._wantsHashChange&&"onhashchange"in window&&!b?i(window).bind("hashchange",this.checkUrl):this._wantsHashChange&&(this._checkUrlInterval=setInterval(this.checkUrl,
            this.interval));this.fragment=a;a=window.location;b=a.pathname==this.options.root;if(this._wantsHashChange&&this._wantsPushState&&!this._hasPushState&&!b)return this.fragment=this.getFragment(null,!0),window.location.replace(this.options.root+"#"+this.fragment),!0;this._wantsPushState&&this._hasPushState&&b&&a.hash&&(this.fragment=this.getHash().replace(s,""),window.history.replaceState({},document.title,a.protocol+"//"+a.host+this.options.root+this.fragment));if(!this.options.silent)return this.loadUrl()},
            stop:function(){i(window).unbind("popstate",this.checkUrl).unbind("hashchange",this.checkUrl);clearInterval(this._checkUrlInterval);m.started=!1},route:function(a,b){this.handlers.unshift({route:a,callback:b})},checkUrl:function(){var a=this.getFragment();a==this.fragment&&this.iframe&&(a=this.getFragment(this.getHash(this.iframe)));if(a==this.fragment)return!1;this.iframe&&this.navigate(a);this.loadUrl()||this.loadUrl(this.getHash())},loadUrl:function(a){var b=this.fragment=this.getFragment(a);return f.any(this.handlers,
            function(a){if(a.route.test(b))return a.callback(b),!0})},navigate:function(a,b){if(!m.started)return!1;if(!b||!0===b)b={trigger:b};var c=(a||"").replace(s,"");this.fragment!=c&&(this._hasPushState?(0!=c.indexOf(this.options.root)&&(c=this.options.root+c),this.fragment=c,window.history[b.replace?"replaceState":"pushState"]({},document.title,c)):this._wantsHashChange?(this.fragment=c,this._updateHash(window.location,c,b.replace),this.iframe&&c!=this.getFragment(this.getHash(this.iframe))&&(b.replace||
            this.iframe.document.open().close(),this._updateHash(this.iframe.location,c,b.replace))):window.location.assign(this.options.root+a),b.trigger&&this.loadUrl(a))},_updateHash:function(a,b,c){c?a.replace(a.toString().replace(/(javascript:|#).*$/,"")+"#"+b):a.hash=b}});var v=g.View=function(a){this.cid=f.uniqueId("view");this._configure(a||{});this._ensureElement();this.initialize.apply(this,arguments);this.delegateEvents()},F=/^(\S+)\s*(.*)$/,w="model,collection,el,id,attributes,className,tagName".split(",");
            f.extend(v.prototype,k,{tagName:"div",$:function(a){return this.$el.find(a)},initialize:function(){},render:function(){return this},remove:function(){this.$el.remove();return this},make:function(a,b,c){a=document.createElement(a);b&&i(a).attr(b);c&&i(a).html(c);return a},setElement:function(a,b){this.$el&&this.undelegateEvents();this.$el=a instanceof i?a:i(a);this.el=this.$el[0];!1!==b&&this.delegateEvents();return this},delegateEvents:function(a){if(a||(a=n(this,"events"))){this.undelegateEvents();
            for(var b in a){var c=a[b];f.isFunction(c)||(c=this[a[b]]);if(!c)throw Error('Method "'+a[b]+'" does not exist');var d=b.match(F),e=d[1],d=d[2],c=f.bind(c,this),e=e+(".delegateEvents"+this.cid);""===d?this.$el.bind(e,c):this.$el.delegate(d,e,c)}}},undelegateEvents:function(){this.$el.unbind(".delegateEvents"+this.cid)},_configure:function(a){this.options&&(a=f.extend({},this.options,a));for(var b=0,c=w.length;b<c;b++){var d=w[b];a[d]&&(this[d]=a[d])}this.options=a},_ensureElement:function(){if(this.el)this.setElement(this.el,
            !1);else{var a=n(this,"attributes")||{};this.id&&(a.id=this.id);this.className&&(a["class"]=this.className);this.setElement(this.make(this.tagName,a),!1)}}});o.extend=r.extend=u.extend=v.extend=function(a,b){var c=G(this,a,b);c.extend=this.extend;return c};var H={create:"POST",update:"PUT","delete":"DELETE",read:"GET"};g.sync=function(a,b,c){var d=H[a];c||(c={});var e={type:d,dataType:"json"};c.url||(e.url=n(b,"url")||t());if(!c.data&&b&&("create"==a||"update"==a))e.contentType="application/json",
            e.data=JSON.stringify(b.toJSON());g.emulateJSON&&(e.contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded",e.data=e.data?{model:e.data}:{});if(g.emulateHTTP&&("PUT"===d||"DELETE"===d))g.emulateJSON&&(e.data._method=d),e.type="POST",e.beforeSend=function(a){a.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override",d)};"GET"!==e.type&&!g.emulateJSON&&(e.processData=!1);return i.ajax(f.extend(e,c))};g.wrapError=function(a,b,c){return function(d,e){e=d===b?e:d;a?a(b,e,c):b.trigger("error",b,e,c)}};var x=function(){},G=function(a,
            b,c){var d;d=b&&b.hasOwnProperty("constructor")?b.constructor:function(){a.apply(this,arguments)};f.extend(d,a);x.prototype=a.prototype;d.prototype=new x;b&&f.extend(d.prototype,b);c&&f.extend(d,c);d.prototype.constructor=d;d.__super__=a.prototype;return d},n=function(a,b){return!a||!a[b]?null:f.isFunction(a[b])?a[b]():a[b]},t=function(){throw Error('A "url" property or function must be specified');}}).call(this);
```

Can anyone tell if this file is ok? I looked for the original version of backbone.js 0.9.2 but couldn't find it.

The scan from Magento is new so it might not be perfected. The file is from a Mirasvit extension.

Comment: Possibly because you're using an old version, if possible, update to [the latest version](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/releases). The [version 0.9.2 is available on cdnjs](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js).

Comment: This question either too broad or opinion-based. How are we supposed to answer whether "this file is ok"? Are we supposed to go read the code of whatever tool declared Backbone to be "compromised" and determine a) how it performs the check that flagged your file, and b) whether the result was a false positive (and thus the tool is buggy)? If someone answers without doing the work I just described, how is it not just someone's uninformed opinion?

Comment: @EmileBergeron I will check the the extension developer.

Comment: @louis They way to answer where this file is ok was if it matched the original backbone.js version which I couldn't find. I was hoping someone had experience with backbone and would know if there were serious vulnerabilities with 0.9.2

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/0.9.2/backbone-min.js

It matches the original code, so the site is not compromised. It is an older version so it might be outdated code.